# Passing Data from a click to load a modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

How do i pass a data from a call to load a modal i.e this var c so i can use it on my controller to use it on my query

```js
$scope.compareMe = function(Data) {
    console.log($scope.cannedLst.name)
    var c = $scope.cannedLst.name;
    $scope.Data = c;
    $scope.modal.show();
  }
```

Comment: you use https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog or you mean Bootstrap modal?

Comment: ng-modal not bootstrap sir @shershen

Comment: $ionicModal i mean ionic modal sir @shershen

Comment: @shershen how do i access the data from another controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller that uses you [$ionicModal](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/) you can pass the data as a scope variable

```
//your main controller
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $ionicModal) {

//you function to get data and call modal
  $scope.compareMe = function(Data) {
    console.log($scope.cannedLst.name)
    var c = $scope.cannedLst.name;
//this is the data we're passing
    $scope.Data = c;
    $scope.modal.show();
  }

//modal configuration (may be 'templateString')
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
//here it states that inside the modal $scope will be == data you've passed
    scope: $scope.Data,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
```